# Dataset designer stops working after Visual Studio 2012 migration

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I just installed new OS & Visual Studio 2012 and opened my project that was created in VS 2010. The project migrated successfully. But I am not able to open my Data set (MySQL) using the Data Set designer. When I double click my dataset in the data sources window, nothing happens. When I click "Configure Data Source with Wizard" after selecting my data source, I get an error saying "Column requires a valid DataType".

I am sure that I am connecting to the same table structures.

A similar kind of problem occurred during the migration from VS2008 to VS2010. I re created the Data set, Table Adapters, etc from the beginner. But I dont want to recreated them again now. I want to fix the existing data set files.

Do I need to manually edit any of the data set files to bring up the designer working?

Clean + Rebuild doesnt solve this problem.

I have the latest MySQL Version(5.5.24) and the latest MySQL .NET Connector(6.6.4)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Any solutions so far?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the Dataset can be opened via the DataSources window (VIEW > Other Windows > Data Sources, while the dataset project is selected in Solution Explorer). After having opened it from there once, it also opens via the Solution Explorer.

Unfortunately the problem comes back after Visual Studio is restarted, even if the Dataset was changed and saved in Studio 2012. At least it's a work around.

Comment: If I go View -> Other Windows -> Data Sources, it just opens the Data Sources window. I still have the problem experienced in the 1st paragraph of the question.

Comment: Yes, and in there it displays the DataSets of the current project. By right clicking, I can open them from there.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the files with the extension .SUO this worked for me.